# Bash I/O Print Records with a matching field

Tags: bash, awk, io

I've been messing around with awk and trying to get more comfortable with bash. My question for you is how can I take in a text file such as:

```
5555
5554 No-match
5555 Match1
2421 No-match
5552 No-match
5555 Match2
5555 Match3
```

And scan the first field ($1) on the first record (in this case: 5555) and then do a search for each remaining record and print the second field ($2) if $1 is a match. Here is what I have wrote:

```
awk '{(NR==1)(id=$1) (NR>1)(if(id==$1))printf("%s\n",$2)}'
```

I am having trouble finding a way to test all records after the first one. I thought that:

```
(NR>1)(if(condition))(action)
```

would result with it performing what I want for records >1 however this does not seem to be the case. Any help would be great!

Comment: The columns are not separated by a tab, simply a space. Also the file I am processing was generated in Unix so there should be no issue there.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. Try:

```
awk 'NR==1{id=$1}NR>1&&id==$1{printf("%s\n",$2)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bash
awk 'NR==1 {id=$1} NR>1 {if (id==$1) printf("%s\n",$2)}'
```

Awk statements consist of a pattern, then an action. The action should be in braces. So here we have two statements. First, if we are on the first row, capture the first field:

```
NR==1 {id=$1}
```

Then, on every row but the first, compare the first field to the captured value, and print the second field if they match:

```
NR>1 {if (id==$1) printf("%s\n",$2)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation here is clear and concise.

Comment: @qorz You should mark the answer as excepted if it works. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out - to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{id=$1}; NR>1{ if ($1==id) {print $2 }}' TestFile
Match1
Match2
Match3
```